# SQL trigger with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I am trying to get two tables to work together with a trigger in MySQL. What this is supposed to do is make a DATETIME in one table change the DATETIME in another table automaticly. This is only going to happen where the 'nr' is equal to '0'.

Pretty new to triggers so would be really nice with some help.

`CREATE TRIGGER paameldte_Tider
    AFTER INSERT ON passeringstid
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (nr  LIKE '0') THEN
        UPDATE paameldte AS pm
        INNER JOIN
        passeringstid AS pt
        ON pm.startnr = pt.startnr AND pm.id = pt.id
        SET pm.starttid = pt.tid;
    END IF;
END`

Error message:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

Comment: And what is the issue with your code?

Comment: I get this error, because I´m new to SQL I´m not sure what the problem is. 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

Comment: You are probably just missing `delimiter` before the definition.